# how to update my label subviews based on how many player are left in the game

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

quick question,

I'm fairly new to programming and have ran into a problem. Im making a game and at the end of every round the winner with highest score during that round is out,  I hide the playerview and label of that player but need to figure out how to make a method so that in my switch for case 4(self.players) the label and playerview that is hidden isn't set and the turn variable rearrange accordingly to what label i took out of the switch.

```
switch (self.players) {
    case 5:
        switch (self.turn) {
            case 1:
                explanationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
                break;
            case 2:
                explanationLabelTwo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
                break;
            case 3:
                explanationLabelThree.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
                break;
            case 4:
                explanationLabelFour.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
                break;
            case 5:
                explanationLabelFive.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
                break;
```

for example if playerFour what is represented by explanationLabelFour won the first round the switch for four players  should be..

```
 switch (self.players) {
case 4:
    switch (self.turn) {
        case 1:
            explanationLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
            break;
        case 2:
            explanationLabelTwo.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
            break;
        case 3:
            explanationLabelThree.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
            break;
        case 4:
            explanationLabelFive.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",score];
            break;
```

The only way I have found to make it work would be to do if statements to to see if each label is hidden then set them accordingly, but its super inefficient. It's a dice game and after three rolls the turn goes up by one.

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give each of your `explanationLabel` a tag, with respect to your `self.turn`

For example,

```
explanationLabel.tag = 1;
explanationLabelTwo.tag = 2;
explanationLabelThree.tag = 3;
.
.
explanationLabelN.tag = N;
```

Now, you've to call a method named something like, `hideLabels`

```
- (void) hideLabels {
    explanationLabel.hidden = YES;
    explanationLabelTwo.hidden = YES;
    explanationLabelThree.hidden = YES;
}
```

You've to call `hideLabels` before outer switch case call,

Then inside the cases, get label object using tag

```
switch (self.players) {
    case 5:
        UILabel *tempExplanationLabel = (UILabel *)[self.view viewWithTag:self.turn];
        tempExplanationLabel.hidden = NO;
}
```

Upto this, you'll show only that label for which the current turn is, if you want you can also change the frame for that particular label for better result visibility. You can do this by assining `explanationLabel.frame` to `tempExplanationLabel.frame`.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you need exactly, but you could set a flag for each player

ie

```
player1.isPlaying = YES;
```

Loop through the current active players.